# ionic 2/3 : offline connection angularFire activation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm building Ionic 3 application with firebase and I want to make offline connection work with AngularFire, I'd seen the documentation and I found this line of code :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

can some help to guide me where to put it and how to relate it with offline capabilities with

```
`import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';`
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I am trying to run this and its not caching any of my realtime data.